# javascript: display form in iframe

Tags: javascript

I am new to the world of programming (I mean really new, like 2 months old)... so I apologize for the really basic question.I have been struggling with this problem for two full days with no idea how to do it.

1. Have a regular page with a form whose fields are hidden. Once you select an option, fields pop up (name, email, etc.).
2. I have an iframe on the same page.
3. **I would like to display the actual form/fields (name, email, etc.) inside the iframe.**
4. Submit form and send data to mysql (php file executing the transmission).  (This part is done, all outside the iframe, except the final message)

Tried to create a function, tried TARGET (this one displays the actual result of the form inside the iframe - successful - data sent to mysql..etc.). But the form is still outside the iframe.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: To put the form in the iframe just make it part of the document that's loaded in the iframe, not the parent document.

Comment: Would you put some commented code here that you have tried unsuccessfully?

Comment: OP, to help us better understand what's going on—why is it exactly that you're using an iframe? In terms of function, what does the `<iframe>` offer you in your use case? 

Often those new to web development—no offense to you at all—see `<iframe>`s as an easy way achieve a desired affect. 

I don't know exactly what you're looking to do, but I promise you we can do it without an iframe.

Comment: the project:left column would be a bunch of options. Middle part would be the iframe, which is actually a very nice iframe with nice css. Left column would be a working area for the users. (These are actually not columns, css design.)The Iframe would be a place to put forms, google map, and even other realty pages. There must be a way to use the onClick to send the form to the iFrame. (onchange to hide/show form) (Someone told me he would rather untangle spaghetti than try to understand what I did, lol, so I am kind of embarrassed to put it in public.) It’s working :)  Thank you for you time.